# Organizar labels verticalmente

Tags: java, swing, layout

Eu queria colocar painéis em posições especificas, então tentei combinar alguns gerenciadores de layout, mas ainda não consegui o resultado que eu preciso.

Eu tentei usar o `gridLayout`, para que os componentes não fossem esticados, mas não tenho certeza se estou fazendo um mal uso dele.

eu tentei fazer isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

onde os quadros pretos são componentes, nesse caso `labels`.

E o resultado que eu obtive foi:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém consegue me demostrar ou indicar um forma de fazer isso?

Segue um exemplo do codigo:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE;

public class PainelPosicao {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new PainelPosicao());
    }

    public PainelPosicao() {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setUndecorated(true);
        jFrame.setContentPane(new Pane());
        jFrame.setSize(500, 300);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    class Pane extends JPanel {

        public Pane() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
            JPanel gridPainel = new JPanel();
            gridPainel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
            gridPainel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

            JPanel painel = new JPanel();
            painel.add(new JLabel("Label 01"));

            JPanel painelProgress = new JPanel();
            painelProgress.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
            painelProgress.add(new JLabel("Label 01"));
            painelProgress.add(new JLabel(".......Label 02 ......"));

            gridPainel.add(painel);
            gridPainel.add(painelProgress);
            add(gridPainel);
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nao entendi o que quer fazer. Quer botar os dois labels de baixo no quadro preto?

Comment: Na verdade, era pro quandro cinza estar dentro do quadro petro, não sei por que ele não ficou. Os labels eu queria centralizar em baixo do quandro cinza

Comment: Precisa dessa classe de painel ai? Eu consigo fazer sem ela, ela ta bastante inutil no codigo

Comment: Da pra fazer isso tudo ai com apenas um painel. Usando GridBagLayout.

Comment: Pode sim, eu vou combinar com a outra pergunta que fiz, ai so fazer o que vc me explicou la

Comment: fiz uma abordagem mais simplista usando apenas um jpanel, conforme havia comentado. Veja na resposta, fica como alternativa.

Comment: @Articuno As duas ficaram excelentes, era exatamente o que eu precisava ! Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o objetivo é alinhar no centro e na posição inferior os dois labels de baixo, consegui fazer assim:

```
import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PainelPosicao {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new PainelPosicao());
    }

    public PainelPosicao() {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setUndecorated(true);
        jFrame.setContentPane(new Pane());
        jFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
        jFrame.pack();
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }



    class Pane extends JPanel {

        public Pane() {

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel painel = new JPanel();
            painel.add(new JLabel("Label 01"));

            JPanel painelProgress = new JPanel();
            painelProgress.setLayout(new BoxLayout(painelProgress, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

            JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Label 01");
            label1.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            painelProgress.add(label1);

            JLabel label2 = new JLabel(".......Label 02 ......");
            label2.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            painelProgress.add(label2);

            add(painel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(painelProgress, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para organizar o painel onde você adiciona os dois labels, eu utilizei o gerenciador de layout [`BoxLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html), que me permite adicionar componentes na orientação vertical. Depois, utilizei o método [`setAlignmentX()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setAlignmentX-float-) pra orientar o `BoxLayout` a alinhar o componente horizontalmente no centro.

---

Tem essa outra abordagem mais simplista, sem utilizar esse tanto de paineis:

```
class Pane2 extends JPanel {

    public Pane2() {

        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Label 01");  
        label1.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        add(label1);

        add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Label 02");
        label2.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        add(label2);

        JLabel label3 = new JLabel(".......Label 03 ......");
        label3.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        add(label3);

    }
}
```

Ainda se utilizando da flexibilidade de uso do `BoxLayout`, nessa abordagem eu organizo os 3 labels no mesmo `JPanel`, e utilizo um recurso de preenchimento, através do método [`createVerticalGlue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html#createVerticalGlue--), que preenche o espaço a partir do label do topo, empurrando os dois labels de baixo até o limite inferior da tela.